# "Your current security settings put your computer at risk" error

Tags: internet-explorer

How I can hide the following error?

> Your current security settings put your computer at risk

[image]

I tried to set *ActiveX controls and plugins*  to *enabled*,

[image]

to add `iexplore.exe` row with `0` value to register
[image]

But nothing helped. How I can disable this prompt?

Comment: Are you trying to maintain your user adjustmensts?  because i am wondering why you did not select to have the thing "fix it for you" or why you do not use the "Restore Advanced Settings" in advanced, and reset security and privacy tab items to defaults?

Comment: I've changed security settings for my need, it works correct but I want to hide this terrible prompt.

Comment: I have active-X left open on my internet settings because it is controlled by my browser (maxthon) and got the same flag when starting the IE (which I do not use) after using windows updates to bring the system up to speed with windows updates it no longer shows.  In Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Action Center the "windows security center service" is turned off the "network access protection" service is turned off, and all  connections are set to "public" as no sharing is used on the computer.  mabey some of that fixes it, I do not know for sure. Note: it then is manually secured

Comment: I've turne off all available options but result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste the following into a `.reg` file and merge with the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Security]   
"DisableSecuritySettingsCheck"=dword:00000001  
"DisableFixSecuritySettings"=dword:00000001  
"DisableSecuritySettings"=dword:00000001
```

This is tested and working on Internet Explorer 10, hope it helps!

Comment: Dave, first welcome to Superuser! To post commands or file content, there's a special environment, called "Preformatted Text" (Icon `{}`) -- or indent the lines with 4 leading spaces.